# Show Database State Durring Debug of a Test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, datagrip

I am testing a Spring Boot application and one of my unit tests modifies a database table.  Is there any way to see the changes to the table during a debug session in IntelliJ Ultimate?

If possible, I would imagine it involve attaching the debugging database session to the Database window.

Comment: What information do you want to see changing? There is e.g. [data editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/table-editor.html), that you may refresh at any time to see data changes.

Comment: @Andrey I have a respository call that adds an entry to a database table.  Ideally, I'd like to see the effects of that repository call to the DB in the middle of a debug session via the data editor integrated into intellij